# Remove button in Angular table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add a remove button to my angular table, but when I click on the button nothing is happening. I have added some code to remove a row in my angular controller and referenced it in the remove button.
 Did I forget something?

So far this is what I have:

My angular controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp')  //extending angular module from first part
    .controller('BudgetAndDetails', function ($scope, BDetail) { //explained about controller in Part2
        $scope.budgetdetails = [];

        BDetail.GetBDetails().then(function (d) {
            $scope.budgetdetails = d.data;
        });
    })
    .factory('BDetail', function ($http) { //explained about factory in Part2
        var fac = {};
        fac.GetBDetails = function () {
            return $http.get('/Budget/BudgetandDetails');
        }
        return fac;
    });

    $scope.removeRow = function (idBudget) {
        var index = -1;
        var comArr = eval($scope.budgetdetails);
        for (var i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++) {
            if (comArr[i].idBudget === idBudget) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index === -1) {
            alert("Something gone wrong");
        }
    $scope.budgetdetails.splice(index, 1);
};
```

My webpage:

```
<div ng-controller="BudgetAndDetails">
    <table class="tableData" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Budget Name</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="O in budgetdetails">
            <tr ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
                <td class="CX"><span>+</span></td>
                <td>{{O.budget.BudgetName}}</td>
                <td>{{O.budget.Year}}</td>
                <td>{{O.budget.Month}}</td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="removeRow(O.budget.idBudget)"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sub">
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <table class="tableData" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>SubCategory</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="a in O.budgetdetails" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
                            <td>{{a.Category}}</td>
                            <td>{{a.Subcategory}}</td>
                            <td>{{a.Amount| currency}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How come this part of code is outside controller ?

```
$scope.removeRow = function (idBudget) {
var index = -1;
var comArr = eval($scope.budgetdetails);
for (var i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++) {
    if (comArr[i].idBudget === idBudget) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (index === -1) {
    alert("Something gone wrong");
}
$scope.budgetdetails.splice(index, 1);
  };
```

> Any scope function should be inside controller.

Paste the same in controller. It will work.

Comment: I moved it inside the controller but the button is still not firing

Comment: Hi Mansa, the code worked after I moved it inside the controller. I had to rebuilt the project. Now my problem is the database is not updating after i delete the row. How do I update the Json and the database?

Comment: Hi @mdiaz , Please mark my answer as accepted and correct in such case. For Database, please ask as a new question with updated code on stack overflow :)

Answer (score 4):

As per your code you are passing Id, instead you need to pass "index".

After passing index you can simply apply splice, so that it will remove that element/row from list.

> webpage

```
......
 <tbody ng-repeat="O in budgetdetails">
<tr ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
            <td class="CX"><span>+</span></td>
            <td>{{O.budget.BudgetName}}</td>
            <td>{{O.budget.Year}}</td>
            <td>{{O.budget.Month}}</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="removeRow($index)"/></td>
 </tr>
........
```

> js controller

```
.....
$scope.removeRow = function (index) {
if (index === -1) {
    alert("Something gone wrong");
}else{
    $scope.budgetdetails.splice(index,1);
}
......
```

Comment: Passing an $index is not suggested as if one use filter , $index would be different from original index in the array.

Comment: @mansa yes you are right, but as here any filtration is not applied ... So to use $index is easy and better solution.

Comment: Easy Yes, Better may be for a college/school project. Search is basic necessity of any project using list.